# forward declaration on python vs using globals()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a global dict like this :

```
mydict = {
   "name1" : {
       "description"   : "random text 1" ,
       "function_name" : foo
    }
}
```

This is a global function in a module that doesn't have a `if __name__ == "__main__":`

That means that I need to declare the foo before I reference it - from what I have tried. Otherwise when I run my code I get `'foo' is not defined`.

Later in one of my other function what i want to do is something like :

```
def randomCaller() :
   # ....
   mydict[ "name1" ][ "function_name"]()
```

Since I don't want to change how the file is structured - an alternative that I have is to use the name and change the above code into :

```
mydict = {
   "name1" : {
       "description"   : "random text 1" ,
       "function_name" : "foo"
    }
}
def randomCaller() :
   # ....
   fname = mydict[ "name1" ][ "function_name"]
   globals()[ fname ]()
```

Is there any concern/risk on the above? Would you suggest something different?

Comment: What's wrong with `mydict[ "name1" ][ "function_name"]()`, and doing `global mydict` inside `randomCaller()`

Comment: Why you need forward declaration of function? I strongly suggest to put declaration of fun before dict.

Comment: *python doesn't have variable declarations*

Comment: this would work fine inside a class with self.function

Comment: Why not: `"function_name" : lambda: foo()`

Comment: because of useless lambda call maybe

Comment: @user8426627 seems like that lambda call is actually serving a specific use.

Answer (score 1):

@MarkMeyer came up with a great workaround for this in the comments:

```
"function_name": lambda *args, **kwargs: foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

(the arguments can be whatever you need them to be. This is the most flexible arrangement, but if you know `foo()` will use a certain set of arguments you can arrange the lambda to mirror that).

Ordinarily, this type of use of a lambda would be pretty useless ("why not just call `foo` in the first place?"). However, in this particular use case, it's uniquely useful, because the name `foo` is only evaluated when the lambda is called, and not when it's assigned.

In other words, this works on my python console:

```
>>> f1 = lambda: foo()
>>> f1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>> def foo():
...     print("Hello World!")
...
>>> f1()
Hello World!
```

---

That said, this solution is hacky, and might play weirdly with namespaces. The *best* way to handle the problem would be to just define `foo()` before defining `mydict`, but if you absolutely must declare `mydict` first, you could also simply declare `"function_name": None` initially, and then set it to `foo()` after you've defined `foo()`:

```
mydict = {
    "name1" : {
       "description"   : "random text 1" ,
       "function_name" : None
    }
}
...
def foo():
    ...
mydict["name1"]["function_name"] = foo
```